# WinRT Enhancing performance for adding Items of Collection to List

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime

I have run over a small performance problem while I was trying to add some Items of an ObservableCollection to a ListView.

Here's the ObservableCollection:

```
    private ObservableCollection<object> children = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children;
        }
    }
```

I'm also using a ContentProperty:

```
[ContentProperty(Name="Children")]
```

Here's the CollectionChanged Event I need to start adding the List:

```
void children_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitGraphics();
    }
```

In InitGraphics(), I will create my List and draw all elements needed for it. There's also a function called SynchronizeList(), which gets called right at the beginning of InitGraphics().

SynchronizeList() looks like this:

```
private void SynchronizeList()
    {
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            //Casting ListViewItem as ValueBoxControl
            ValueBoxControl control = (ValueBoxControl)item;

            //Standards and needed attributes
            control.ValueTextBox.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            control.ClipColor = ClipColor;
            control.Foreground = this.Foreground;

            //Add the Item to the List
            List.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Now, as you can see, my ListView is called **List** and Items are Usercontrols called **ValueBoxControl**. The standards and attributes have to be the same for every item and they should be unchangeable.

I need the SynchronizeList() function in a few other functions (for example: When the List gets toggled twice, I delete all Items and add them again with SynchronizeList(), etc.).

The problem occurs when I add about 50+ Items, because it obviously has to run through the foreach loop 50 times and add each item. While debugging, I have noticed that the children Collection doesn't have all 50 items from the start. It first has 1 item, then 2, then 3, etc. 
Which means that the SynchronizeList() gets called 50 times, while first adding 1 item, then 2, then 3, etc.

I have tried many things (like working with e.NewItems in the CollectionChangedEvent), but I currently see no possible solution.

Here's a complete example out of my fragments which shows my problem:

```
//ContentProperty to receive Items from XAML with the help of an ObservableCollection
[ContentProperty(Name="Children")]
public sealed partial class ListViewControl : ValueBoxControl
{
    //Create a new ListView
    ListView List = new ListView();

    //Initialization
    public ListViewControl()
    { 
        //Events
        children.CollectionChanged += children_CollectionChanged;
    }

    //ObservableCollection to receive Items from XAML
    private ObservableCollection<object> children = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children;
        }
    }

    //Event which gets called whenever the List in XAML gets changed
    void children_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calls the function to draw the List
        InitGraphics();
    }    

    private void InitGraphics()
    {
        SynchronizeList();
        if (List.Items.Counter >= 1)
        {
            //Draw the ListView with a custom design
        }
    }

    private void SynchronizeList()
    {
        //Get each item in the ObservableCollection and add some attributes
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            //ListViewItem casted as ValueBoxControl
            ValueBoxControl control = (ValueBoxControl)item;
            //Standards & Limitations
            control.ValueTextBox.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            control.ClipColor = ClipColor;
            control.Foreground = this.Foreground;
            //Add Item to ListView
            List.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem I have here is that the CollectionChanged Event gets called 50 times for 50 items, each time receiving a new item, instead of receiving them all in one go.

Comment: I'm confused about what the `List` property is - is that the `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have written it in the first sentence after the last code snippet. It is a simple ListView: 
        `ListView List = new ListView();`

Comment: Ah, right. Your code is quite hard to follow given that it's fragmented and you've got bits which require extra description. A short but *complete* example would be a lot easier to understand...

Comment: Well, the whole ListControl I'm using these functions in has 600 lines of code, so I extracted these functions to keep it short. If you think it would be of an advantage, I can still post the whole code. But short and clear, my problem is that the CollectionChanged Event gets called 50 times for 50 items, instead of once for all 50 items.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted the whole of your actual code. I'd like a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem, and does nothing else. You might want to look at the `ReplaceAll` method though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I see. I have added a complete example to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the documentation for [`ItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcollection.aspx), I *suspect* you want the [`ReplaceAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcollection.replaceall.aspx) method:

> For implementations that track a "changed" event, the initial reset fires an event, but the items added don't fire discrete per-item events.

So something like:

```
private void SynchronizeList()
{
    // Set properties in each item
    foreach (var item in children)
    {
        //ListViewItem casted as ValueBoxControl
        ValueBoxControl control = (ValueBoxControl)item;
        //Standards & Limitations
        control.ValueTextBox.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        control.ClipColor = ClipColor;
        control.Foreground = this.Foreground;
    }
    List.Items.ReplaceAll(children.ToArray());
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's an `AddRange` which is what you really want... it's at least worth giving that a try.

Comment: Alright, the idea seems nice to me, I'll try to implement it :) Thanks